# Grails: Getting the controller to do some parallel data processing and rendering the results iteratively

Tags: grails, parallel-processing, executorservice

I'm trying to get the controller to call a service method that does some data processing, then render the results, and then do it over and over again till no more data processing is required. The problem is that the controller keeps processing data without rendering the inbetween results. He just keeps on calling the index method (where both calculations and rendering methods are being called) without rendering anything.

This is the index function:

```
def index() {
   def systemStatus = null

   ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()

   Future future = executor.submit(new Callable(){
      public Object call() throws Exception {
         println("calculations thread is: " + Thread.currentThread().id)
         def temp = systemStatusService.calculateSystemStatus()
         return temp
       }
   })

   systemStatus = future.get()
   executor.shutdown()

   Thread.currentThread().sleep((long)5000)
   if(systemStatus["additionalInfo"]["stillGotWorkToDo"]){
      renderSystemStatus(systemStatus)
      index()
   }
   else{
      render("No data to render!!")
   }
}
```

I want to call the index() method again after the rendering has been done.

I have tried using the executorService to parallely process data and do the redndering, but if i put the render function in the executor service i get an error.

The methods look like this:

calculateSystemStatus method in a separate service:

```
class SystemStatusService {
    def queueManagementService

    def calculateSystemStatus(){
        def stillGotWorkToDo = true

        def trackState = queueManagementService.getTrackState("taxi", Taxi.getAll()*.name)
        trackState << queueManagementService.getTrackState("turnaround", Turnaround.getAll()*.name)

        stillGotWorkToDo = queueManagementService.manageMoveRequests()

        def obstructingTaxi = null
        def boardedTaxi = null
        def allocatedTaxiZone = null
        def turnaround = null

        def pendingMoveRequests = queueManagementService.getPendingMoveRequests()
        pendingMoveRequests.each{
            allocatedTaxiZone = queueManagementService.getZone(it.allocatedTaxi.position, it.allocatedTaxi.rail)
            it.currentTaxiZone = allocatedTaxiZone

            if(it.targetType == "taxi"){
                obstructingTaxi = queueManagementService.findObstructingTaxi(it.allocatedTaxi.name, it.id)
                it.obstructingTaxi = obstructingTaxi
            }
            else{
                turnaround = Turnaround.findByName(it.targetName)
                if(turnaround){
                    boardedTaxi = turnaround.boardedTaxi
                    it.boardedTaxi = boardedTaxi
                }
            }
        }

        obstructingTaxi = null
        boardedTaxi = null
        allocatedTaxiZone = null
        turnaround = null

        def executingMoveRequests = queueManagementService.getExecutingMoveRequests()
        executingMoveRequests.each{
            allocatedTaxiZone = queueManagementService.getZone(it.allocatedTaxi.position, it.allocatedTaxi.rail)
            it.currentTaxiZone = allocatedTaxiZone

            if(it.targetType == "taxi"){
                obstructingTaxi = queueManagementService.findObstructingTaxi(it.allocatedTaxi.name, it.id)
                it.obstructingTaxi = obstructingTaxi
            }
            else{
                turnaround = Turnaround.findByName(it.targetName)
                if(turnaround){
                    boardedTaxi = turnaround.boardedTaxi
                    it.boardedTaxi = boardedTaxi
                }
            }
        }

        def additionalInfo = [:]
        additionalInfo["stillGotWorkToDo"] = stillGotWorkToDo
        additionalInfo["pending"] = pendingMoveRequests
        additionalInfo["executing"] = executingMoveRequests

        return [trackState: trackState, additionalInfo: additionalInfo]
    }
}
```

The render method:

```
def renderSystemStatus(def systemStatus){
    def trackState = systemStatus["trackState"]
    def pending = systemStatus["additionalInfo"]["pending"]
    def executing = systemStatus["additionalInfo"]["executing"]
    def obstructingTaxi = null
    def boardedTaxi = null
    def allocatedTaxiZone = null

    render("Track state: <br/>")
     trackState.each(){
         render("$it.key $it.value<br/>")
     }

     render("<br/>Pending move requests: <br/>")
     pending.each(){
         if(!it.isAttached()){
             it.attach()
         }

         if(it.targetType == "taxi"){
             allocatedTaxiZone = it.currentTaxiZone
             if(it.obstructingTaxi){
                 obstructingTaxi = it.obstructingTaxi
                 render("$it.allocatedTaxi.name on (current taxi zone: $allocatedTaxiZone.name, rail slot $it.allocatedTaxi.rail.slot) -> $it.destinationZone.name ($it.destination, rail slot: $it.destinationZone.rail.slot) --------- ['$it.targetName' going to $it.microDestination] obstructed by ${obstructingTaxi.name} <br/>")
             }
             else{
                 render("$it.allocatedTaxi.name on (current taxi zone: $allocatedTaxiZone.name, rail slot $it.allocatedTaxi.rail.slot) -> $it.destinationZone.name ($it.destination, rail slot: $it.destinationZone.rail.slot) --------- ['$it.targetName' going to $it.microDestination] <br/>")
             }
         }
         else{
             allocatedTaxiZone = it.currentTaxiZone
             if(it.boardedTaxi){
                 boardedTaxi = it.boardedTaxi
                 render("$it.allocatedTaxi.name on (current taxi zone: $allocatedTaxiZone.name, rail slot $it.allocatedTaxi.rail.slot) -> $it.destinationZone.name ($it.destination, rail slot: $it.destinationZone.rail.slot) --------- ['$it.targetName' going to $it.microDestination], boarding taxi: ${boardedTaxi.name} <br/>")
             }
             else{
                 render("$it.allocatedTaxi.name on (current taxi zone: $allocatedTaxiZone.name, rail slot $it.allocatedTaxi.rail.slot) -> $it.destinationZone.name ($it.destination, rail slot: $it.destinationZone.rail.slot) --------- ['$it.targetName' going to $it.microDestination] <br/>")
             }
         }
     }

     render("<br/> Executing move requests:  <br/>")
     executing.each(){
         if(!it.isAttached()){
             it.attach()
         }

         if(it.targetType == "taxi"){
             allocatedTaxiZone = it.currentTaxiZone
             if(it.obstructingTaxi){
                 obstructingTaxi = it.obstructingTaxi
                 render("$it.allocatedTaxi.name on (current taxi zone: $allocatedTaxiZone.name, rail slot $it.allocatedTaxi.rail.slot) -> $it.destinationZone.name ($it.destination, rail slot: $it.destinationZone.rail.slot) --------- ['$it.targetName' going to $it.microDestination] obstructed by ${obstructingTaxi.name} <br/>")
             }
             else{
                 render("$it.allocatedTaxi.name on (current taxi zone: $allocatedTaxiZone.name, rail slot $it.allocatedTaxi.rail.slot) -> $it.destinationZone.name ($it.destination, rail slot: $it.destinationZone.rail.slot) --------- ['$it.targetName' going to $it.microDestination] <br/>")
             }
         }
         else{
             allocatedTaxiZone = it.currentTaxiZone
             if(it.boardedTaxi){
                 boardedTaxi = it.boardedTaxi
                 render("$it.allocatedTaxi.name on (current taxi zone: $allocatedTaxiZone.name, rail slot $it.allocatedTaxi.rail.slot) -> $it.destinationZone.name ($it.destination, rail slot: $it.destinationZone.rail.slot) --------- ['$it.targetName' going to $it.microDestination], boarding taxi: ${boardedTaxi.name} <br/>")
             }
             else{
                 render("$it.allocatedTaxi.name on (current taxi zone: $allocatedTaxiZone.name, rail slot $it.allocatedTaxi.rail.slot) -> $it.destinationZone.name ($it.destination, rail slot: $it.destinationZone.rail.slot) --------- ['$it.targetName' going to $it.microDestination] <br/>")
             }
         }
     }
}
```

How can i achieve to get the desired actions? First calculate, then render, if needed, again, and so forth.

Comment: I don't think this will work the way you want - calling render and recursively calling your index method. I think you're better off having a simple GSP page that loads the initial results of your lookup and then use Javascript/AJAX to poll for a results every N seconds.

Comment: so the calculations function should always be executing in the background (say i start the index method without the render function upon pressing some button) and i should use a GSP file to render the results every N seconds?